# Can not save checkboxes values into database using ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to save data from a modal to a database using ajax.
The data from the modal contains a number of checkboxes that i want to save to the database.
All the fields from the data I am trying to save to the database are all saving excluding that of the checkboxes that are checked.
After the ajax runs, all the columns save their corresponding data but the column to save the value of the checkboxes becomes null.

This is my checkboxes code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#saveRoute').click(function(){
        var myCat = [];
        var categories;
        $.each($("input[name='categories']:checked"), function(){        
            myCat.push($(this).val());
            categories =  myCat.join(", ");                
        });
        alert("My categories are: " +  categories);
        console.log(myCat);
    });
  });
```

This is  my ajax code:

```
function saveRoute(){
        var active = "";
        var from_location = $('#from_location').val();
        var to_location = $('#to_location').val();
        var categories = categories;
        var leaving_date = $('#leaving_date').val();
        var return_job = $('#return_job').val();
        var route_name = $('#route_name').val();
        var expires = "";
        var user_id = <?php echo $my_id; ?>;
        var type_of_vehicle = $('#type_of_vehicle').val();

        $.ajax({
            url:'<?php echo site_url('router/add_route');?>',
            method:'POST',
            data:{
                active : 'Yes',
                from_location : from_location,
                to_location : to_location,
                categories : categories,
                leaving_date : leaving_date,
                return_job : return_job,
                route_name : route_name,
                expires : '2018-05-15',
                user_id : user_id,
            },
              success: function(data) {
                alert(categories);
                console.log(data);
                $('#routeModal').modal('hide');
                alert('Route has been successfully added');

                location.reload();
      }
        });
    }
```

This is my modal code:

```
<div >
    <label for="categories">Select Categories</label>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="" id="categories_1" name="categories" value="Furniture & Appliances">Furniture & Appliances</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="" id="categories_2" name="categories" value="Home Removals">Home Removals</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="" id="categories_3" name="categories" value="Specialist & Antiques">Specialist & Antiques</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="" id="categories_4" name="categories" value="Cars & Vehicles">Cars & Vehicles</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="" id="categories_5" name="categories" value="Boats">Boats</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="" id="categories_6" name="categories" value="Freight">Freight</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="" id="categories_7" name="categories" value="Industrial">Industrial</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="" id="categories_8" name="categories" value="Livestock">Livestock</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="" id="categories_9" name="categories" value="Piano">Piano</li>

        <li></li><input type="checkbox" class="" id="categories_10" name="categories" value="Office Removals">Office Removals
        <li></li><input type="checkbox" class="" id="categories_11" name="categories" value="Packaged Items & Parcels">Packaged Items & Parcels
        <li></li><input type="checkbox" class="" id="categories_12" name="categories" value="Man Power Only">Man Power Only
        <li></li><input type="checkbox" class="" id="categories_13" name="categories" value="Other">Other
        <li></li><input type="checkbox" class="" id="categories_14" name="categories" value="Hourly Rate">Hourly Rate
        <li></li><input type="checkbox" class="" id="categories_15" name="categories" value="Ebay">Ebay
        <li></li><input type="checkbox" class="" id="categories_16" name="categories" value="Motorbikes">Motorbikes
        <li></li><input type="checkbox" class="" id="categories_17" name="categories" value="Vehicle Parts">Vehicle Parts
        <li></li><input type="checkbox" class="" id="categories_18" name="categories" value="Clearance">Clearance 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Cat" name="Cat" valeu="">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your saveRoute onClick function appears to generate a list of categories correctly both as myCat[] and the string categories. But these are local variables to this function and are lost as soon as the function completes executing.

Separately, in `function saveRoute()` you declare `var categories = categories;` which will set categories to undefined.

You need to pass the results from first operation to the second one. The quick and dirty way to do this would be to move the onClick code into the `saveRoute` function and generate the categories variable right when it is needed.

There are other ways to achieve this as well: global variable (not preferred), the module pattern to add scope to an otherwise global variable, or remove your category code from the onClick handler and make it its own function that returns myCat[]. The details of these methods are beyond the scope of this question.